# Which of the following vectors are in R(T)?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T: {\mathbb R}^2 \rightarrow {\mathbb R}^2$ be the linear operator given by the formula $T(x,y) = (2x-y,-8x
+4y)$. Which of the following vectors are in $R(T)$? $\quad$ $(-3, 12); (1,-4
);(5,0)$.

If I plug them in the equation, I'll get:

$T(-3,12) = (-18,72)$

$T(1,-4) = (6,-24)$

$T(5,0) = (10, -40)$

How to decide which one is in $R(T)$?

Comment: What is $\det T$? What does that tell you about the columns of the matrix representation? How can you use this to check if the given vectors are in the range space?

Comment: Does $R$ stand for “range” or “row space?”

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the *domain* and the *range* of a function. The range of a linear transformation $T$ is the set of those vectors $v$ for which there exists some vector $u$ such that $T(u)=v$.

So to find out if $v$ is in the range of $T$, you must solve the equation $T (u) =v$ to find $u$.